# bash rematch as chroot

Tags: bash, chroot

I'm using this in my script and it works fine on my root server and on some others I tested.

But there's a problem when using it on my webhosting (Hosted Plesk): The chrooted shell, it doesn't output anything. Just quits. My webhoster said I need to use the absolute paths, but I dont know how to apply this on the bash rematch.

```
#!/bin/bash 
str='"<result="Abc1234" />"'
regex='<result="([0-9a-zA-Z._-/:]*)" />'
[[ $str =~ $regex ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

(My first post here, sorry if I forgot something or misformatted this whole post)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165014/discussion-on-question-by-simon-bash-rematch-as-chroot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the discussion below the question it turned out that the issue is related to different default locales on the servers. Make sure that you are running the command with the right locale:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 bash script.sh
```

(`en_US.UTF-8`) turned out to be the right locale in your case.

---

PS: Please also keep in mind what [Ondrej K.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48756296/171318) says.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
regex='<result="([0-9a-zA-Z._-/:]*)" />'
```

say:

```
regex='<result="([0-9a-zA-Z._/:-]*)" />'
```

`-` is moved to where it no longer can be considered meaning a range.

Actually I am a surprised it worked on the other system. I've replaced `&& echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` with `; echo $?` (this was another possible debugging step) and was getting `2` which according to `man bash` means "syntactically incorrect regular expression".

If this doesn't help. Than we must be seeing different reason, way our shell interpret the script, but in any case printing the return status could then be the next step to take.

Comment: Good point. But it turned out that this was not the main problem here.

Comment: Yep, you were discussing as I was typing this. Still surprised, my (mostly vanilla 4.4.18) bash would reject that as described. Found another host with 4.3.48, same thing. I'd use `en_US.UTF-8` but setting `LANG=C`, no difference either way. In any case, good catch. Locales can be pain in the neck.